# Relationship between PH and PPM in Hydroponics solution

Tags: vegetables, hydroponic, ph

I'm making some Hydroponics system, which will automatically measure `PPM` in water for Deep water system. I'm able to measure `PPM` every x minutes, but I will have to measure `PH` manually, because I don't have a sensor for that.

I would like to know if there is a relationship between these two values, so for example: if PPM changes rapidly I can deduce that PH went up/down in the same time and I have to measure the current value.

PPM is from `VEGETABLE LIFE` fertilizer mix (liquid)

Comment: ppm of which solute?  Not all affect the pH.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is no relationship between pH and ppm. If you pick one ion there is a relationship.

Comment: Thank you.  So I need both